# Setting DisplayName on InputNumber control in Blazor form is NOT used in ErrorMessage upon submit/validation

Tags: asp.net-core, validation, blazor, data-annotations

Upon validation of my SUBMIT for the CRUD page...

```
<EditForm Model="CustomerData" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" OnInvalidSubmit="HandleInvalidSubmit">
   <DataAnnotationsValidator />
   <ValidationSummary />
```

I get this ERROR for a value of 0 (zero) -- which does NOT show the field's "DisplayName":

**'ID_CUSTOMER's value must be greater or equal to 1.**

The InputNumber control with DisplayName is:

```
<InputNumber class="m-sm-0 pl-sm-1 py-sm-1 form-control" 
@bind-Value="CustomerData.ID_CUSTOMER" DisplayName="FCI Key" />
```

The data-model field is defined as follows:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "'{0}' is required.")]
[Range(1, 9999, ErrorMessage = "'{0}'s value must be greater or equal to {1}.")]
public int ID_CUSTOMER { get; set; }
```

As you can see the ErrorMessage shows the model bound field-name (**ID_CUSTOMER**) not the DisplayName (**FCI Key**).

The reason I did NOT enter the [DisplayName...] in the model, is that I may use a different DisplayName based on a user's role in the application.

So I suppose my question is...Why is the InputNumber "DisplayName" NOT being used in the validation ErrorMessage {0} substitution?

Thanks...John

Comment: Hi @John D, you may misunderstand the `InputBase.DisplayName`. This attribute can change the error message field name with InputBase build-in error. For example, InputNumber must be a number, InputDate must be a date. If you do not fill in with a number/date, it will generate the error message with DisplayName.  `InputBase.DisplayName` **cannot make effect on the Data Annotation**.  Also this attribute supports from .net 5.  Refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#display-name-support-1

Comment: Thank you Rena...You have helped me understand.  Very Good!!!...thx John

Comment: Hi @John D, glad to help you. I convert the comment to answer now. Could you please accept as answer which can also help others? Thank you so much.

Comment: Gladly, @Rena. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may misunderstand the `InputBase.DisplayName`. This attribute can change the error message field name with `InputBase` build-in error. For example, `InputNumber` must be a number, `InputDate` must be a date. If you do not fill in with a number/date, it will generate the error message with DisplayName. `InputBase.DisplayName` **cannot make effect on the Data Annotation**. Also this attribute supports from .net 5.

Refer to:

[Display name support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#display-name-support-1)